# Most efficient way to farm gold on Marvel Contest of Champions?

Tags: marvel-contest-champions

I have the feeling that before v5.0 release, everyone was sitting on a pile of gold. I used to have 500k. Now that I got a couple of 4* and I no longer need to rank up 2*, I see my gold just going down the drain.

What is the most efficient way to farm gold on Marvel Contest of Champions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grinding the 2-star arena is the best way to farm gold. It costs 100 gold to find a match, but you get back 190 gold plus 330 battle chips if you win all three fights in that match. The big payoff comes when you cash in the battle chips for arena crystals. I normally save battle chips until I have enough for 40-50 arena crystals (80k-100k battle chips), and often wind up gaining 100k-200k gold (among other rewards) when I open them.

I save up battle chips and cash them in once a week. Here are my most recent rewards:

- **80k battle chips** (40 arena crystals) - **152k gold**, 120 units, 5 tier-3 ISO-8, 2 tier-4 ISO-8
- **120k battle chips** (60 arena crystals) - **180k gold**, 285 units, 11 tier-3 ISO-8, 1 tier-4 ISO-8
- **80k battle chips** (40 arena crystals) - **136k gold**, 75 units, 2 tier-3 ISO-8, 2 tier-4 ISO-8
- **90k battle chips** (45 arena crystals) - **142k gold**, 135 units, 6 tier-3 ISO-8, 1 tier-4 ISO-8
- **100k battle chips** (50 arena crystals) - **142k gold**, 270 units, 4 tier-3 ISO-8, 3 tier-4 ISO-8, 1 3-star Punisher, 1 full energy refill

Comment: @ChaoticGabibo The returns for 1v1 are pretty low. If you factor in the cost of each match, you might even be losing gold. I typically only play it in hopes of duping my 2-star Punisher.

Comment: I'll have to get a more scientific approach by opening something like 1000 crystals and check it out by myself. I remember opening a lot of 750 gold from those crystals. Don't worry I'll double check. If you find something out please update your question. Thx again.

Comment: @ChaoticGabibo Sure, no problem.  I'll update my answer as I get more data.